# creating two-dimensional array dynamically in continuous memory block

Tags: c++

I was trying to create 2D array in a continuous memory block, but it is giving M continuous block, each of N size.

```
int **arr = new int*[M];
for (int i = 0 ; i < M ; i++ )
{
     arr[i] = new int[N];
}
```

How to create 2D array in a continuous memory block?

Comment: **Please** don't do this yourself. Use boost::multi_array.

Comment: Yeah, don't learn anything new, just code like monkey, please.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
int *buffer=new int[M*N];
int **arr=new int*[M];
for(int i=0;i<M;++i)
    arr[i]=buffer+i*N;
```

Actually it's not necessary to store arr pointers - they can be calculated when needed.

Comment: Would this approach work if one wants to create an array of object of some class?

Comment: I don't see any problems here. Constructors are called once.

Comment: Yup. I noticed that. By the way, I was thinking, can we make it work for non-default constructor, where each object in the array should be initialized with different values?

Comment: In that case we will have to use placement new, but not for allocation of pointers, but for objects themselves. So we would just allocate space for TObject[M*N] and then M*N times call "new (&TObject[index])(something)"

Comment: And if values are different, that "something" may be a function with some arguments...